# Vue3 css v-bind() not working with external script

Tags: css, binding, vuejs3

I'm trying to make v-bind within css work based on this feature:
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#state-driven-dynamic-css
and https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/231

```
<template>
  <div class="text">Test1</div>
  {{ color }} <!-- This works -->
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        color: 'blue',
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .text {
    color: v-bind(color); /* This works */
    font-size: 20px; /* This works */
  }
</style>
```

But when I put the script in an external file the `v-bind` won't work anymore:

```
<template>
  <div class="text">Test2</div>
  {{ color }} <!-- This works -->
</template>

<script lang="js" src="./Test2.js"></script>

<style scoped>
  .text {
    color: v-bind(color); /* This doesn't work :( */
    font-size: 20px; /* This works */
  }
</style>
```

If I put the script in the same file but use a class construction it also doesn't work:

```
<template>
  <div class="text">Test3</div>
  {{ color }} <!-- This works -->
</template>

<script>
  import { Options } from 'vue-class-component';
  import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';

  @Options({
    data() {
      return {
        color: 'red',
      }
    },
  })
  export default class Test3 extends Vue {
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .text {
    color: v-bind(color); /* This doesn't work :( */
    font-size: 20px; /* This works */
  }
</style>
```

Any suggestions as to why it only works with a simple in-file script but breaks down when the code becomes a little more complex?

The `{{ color }}` binding in the template is just fine in all cases so it's purely the css binding that's the issue!

My ideal situation of course would be to load the class-construction from an external file.

Comment: could it be because of the `<style>` being `scoped`?

Comment: No, that was just so I could run the two versions together

Answer (score 0):

Brother, I think my problems are similar to yours.
I want to use `v-bind` to implement custom scrollbars and adapt to the dark theme mode of my system,but it doesn't work.Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script setup>
</script>

<style lang="scss">
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  height: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  display: block;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: v-bind("$store.state.isDark ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: v-bind("$store.state.isDark ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'");

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

Then I found that by adding any content, even a comment, to the `setup`, `v-bind` was effective:

```
<script setup>
    const a = 1
</script>
```

```
<script setup>
 // Even a comment
</script>
```

Therefore, I think whether `vue` will not parse and compile the `v-bind` used in `style` when the `setup` content is empty? It seems that it thinks my current component is a pure UI component. I don't know, I guess so. You know, `vue` officially designed `v-bind` to implement `css in js`. The original purpose is to enable us to use variables in setup, but we didn't do that.